# Get hard drive to spin up upon mouse movement

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

My storage drive which does not contain the OS stops spinning after a few minutes.  This is annoying and totally defeats the purpose of having a fast access drive. The drive will NOT spin up when I use the mouse!  It only spins up when accessed.

However, I don't want it to spin all the time.  I would like it to spin up anytime there is mouse activity so it is at the ready when I am using the computer, but go to sleep during inactivity.

Can anyone think of a trick to get a secondary drive to spin up on a mouse movement?

Comment: Well, since you're the only one that knows what OS you have, you're gonna have to tackle this one yourself.

Comment: This question is useless without knowing what operating system you're using.  (And really, I'd just set it to spin all the time.  That's much simpler and shouldn't hurt the drive.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows 7 change the hard drive sleep timer to something like 180 minutes. The sleep function will still work as normal so if that's set to 30 minutes everything will still spin down after 30 minutes but whilst the PC is awake it will take at least 180 minutes of disk inactivity before the disk spins down.

Comment: Actually I did write Windows 7 the first time, and this site blew that line away by accident when I re-loaded the page.... forgot to re-type it.

Comment: I like this solution BJ292, and will try it, but some drives have sleep timers in their firmware.  We'll see.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this worked!  Nice tip....

Comment: If you actually let your computer sleep when you're not using it, *why not just set the timer to 'Never' instead of a large number*?  That way the drives will only stop if the system goes to sleep.  If you DON'T let your computer sleep, then this still runs into the original problem.  Obviously you can choose an arbitrarily large number and pick a point that works for you, but the question sort of implies that they don't want it EVER spinning down if the system's in use.